# how can i make a variable to save the selected color from colorPicker component as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

i just asking if i make a colorPicker component in adobeAnimate how can i save the current selected color to a variable that i will use it to change a mc color ?

[image: Component Parameters]

Answer (score 3):

the color is an uint value,

```
var color:uint;
var colorpick:ColorPicker;
color = colorpick.selectedColor;
```

you may want to set an event listener to detect when new color picked.

```
colorpick.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, colorPicked);
function colorPicked(e:ColorPickerEvent):void {
    color = (e.target as ColorPicker).selectedColor;
}
```

Comment: i have this error Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 7, Column 24 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ColorPickerEvent.

Comment: @ibrahimHajjaj this error tells you must include this class definition to your code before using it `import fl.event.ColorPickerEvent;`

Comment: thxx that works but i have this error see >>
http://g27i.imgup.net/2016-12-18249a.png

Comment: @ibrahimHajjaj use the [**`Edit`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41189821/edit) button under your Question to paste your code, use that `{ }` icon during edit mode. Otherwise no one can fix code in a picture...